# How to prevent Visual Studio momentary text editor content resize upon entering Debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

On Visual Studio 2010, pressing F5 to Start Debugging causes the text editor window content to be redrawn slightly reduced in scale, then almost immediately redrawn at full again. How can I prevent this? It is enough for an annoying slow-down in my usage via RDP. Thanks.

Comment: Dang good question. It is very annoying.